# hardhat/console.sol can print in web3 provide？ or just print in JSVM?

Tags: solidity, remix

i deploy contract(use console.log) in my Private blockchain(local net). where to find the print message?
i use  geth run my Private blockchain. In Terminal , i can not find the print message.
add more image to expression my question
my private blockchain Terminal .
[image]

i deploy in my private blockchain
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use the `console.log` functionality in remix. Here's a sample contract loaded on remix that uses `console.log` to print "Print something out":

[image]

After compiling you have to deploy the code:

[image]

Below the deploy button you would see the deployed contract:

[image]

Expand it and call the test function by clicking `test` button and you would see the output in the terminal:

[image]

For convenience, I am also sharing the code here:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.15;
import "hardhat/console.sol";
contract TestContract {
    constructor() {
    }

    function test() public view { 
      console.log("Print something out");
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks bro.  i deploy to my Private blockchain. how to find consoleLog in   Private blockchain. i know how to use in remix(jsvm environment).